# React native pass to renderItem custom components?

Tags: reactjs, native, flatlist

i'm currently trying to implement a horizontal FlatList. I'm aware that i can render list of items pretty easly inside the renderItem by just looping it through... but can i actually pass a custom component inside ?

This is my array filled with custom components i created:

```
const arrayOfCustomComponents = [<Home/>,<News/>,<History/>,<Stats/>,<Settings />];
```

Given this array, can i pass each index inside renderItem to be rendered ?

```
 <Animated.FlatList
    data={data} 
    keyExtractor={item => item.key}
    horizontal
    showsHorizontalScrollIndicator={false}
    pagingEnabled
    bounces={false}
    renderItem={({item}) =>{
        return <View>
          {arrayOfCustomComponents[item.key]}
      </View> 
    }}
     
   />
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You cannot access an `array` elements like you've done in your example. The keys of an array are `0, 1, 2, ....`

What you can do instead is to store your components in an object like that:

```
const DATA = [
  {
    id: 'comp1',
    description: 'This is component 1',
  },
  {
    id: 'comp2',
    description: 'This is component 2',
  }
];

const Comp1 = () => {
  return (
    <View><Text>This is component 1</Text></View>
  )
}

const Comp2 = () => {
  return (
    <View><Text>This is component 2</Text></View>
  )
}

const mapOfComponents = {
  comp1: <Comp1 />,
  comp2: <Comp2 />
};

function App() {
  return (
    <View>
      <FlatList
        data={DATA}
        renderItem={({ item }) => {
          return (
            mapOfComponents[item.id]
          )
        }
      }
        keyExtractor={item => item.id}
      />
    </View>
  );
}
```